# How to create Cocos2d-x v3.0 Beta 2 android ndk project

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I got the build successful with cocos2d-x v2.2.2. Then I follow [this tutorial](http://bradialabs.com/create-cocos2d-x-3-0-beta-project/) to build   cocos2d-x v3.0 beta 2 project
 
The command `project-creator` worked fine and I can create all supported platform projects.
Everything is ok except I have an error with `build_native.py` script:

```
line 25
print "Can't know cpuinfo, use default 1 cpu"
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

As I don't have any experiment with python, so I have no idea with this bug.
Here is my environment detail:

- Latest python for windows 3.3.4
- Windows 8, 64 bit
- Latest android sdk r22.3, ndk r9c
- Already set these environment variables: `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`, `NDK_ROOT`, `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform_tools`, `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools`

For the variable `NDK_MODULE_PATH`, I can't find folder like`platform\third_party\android\prebuilt` in cocos2d-x v3.0, so I don't know what to do with it 
Do I miss something?

**Update**: after searching on google, I found that on python 3, print should be use as method, like `print("")`, then I replace all tabs by spaces to avoid `inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation` error. But I still got another exception:

```
 The Selected NDK toolchain version was 4.8 !
 make.exe: *** D:\SycnDir\game: No such file or directory.  Stop.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "D:\My Games\proj.android\build_native.py", line 166, in <module>
 build(opts.ndk_build_param,opts.android_platform,opts.build_mode)
 File "D:\My Games\proj.android\build_native.py", line 153, in build
 do_build(cocos_root, ndk_root, app_android_root,ndk_build_param,sdk_root,android_platform,build_mode)
 File "D:\My Games\proj.android\build_native.py", line 89, in do_build
  raise Exception("Build dynamic library for project [ " + app_android_root +
 " ] fails!")
 Exception: Build dynamic library for project [ D:\My Games\proj.android ] fails!
```

Comment: please don't tag cocos2d-x questions with the cocos2d-iphone tag (a different engine using a different programming language)

Comment: Thanks, it's my mistake. I don't recognize it is a wrong tag

Comment: What did you do with the NDK_MODULE_PATH issue? Did it have anything to do with your problem? It being the last question in your post I thought it was your main issue.

Comment: `NDK_MODULE_PATH` only needed for cocos2d-x verion 2x. I don't do anything with this variable in version 3x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I can make it worked. The exception is raised on these lines:

```
 if os.system(command) != 0
  raise Exception(“Build dynamic library for project [ " + app_android_root + " ] fails!”)
```

And I figure out space characters on my folder path caused ndk build failed. I can't believe this stupid bug make me waste two days. 
Now I just move my project into a folder without space and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The cocos2d-x 3.0 beta only works with Python 2.7 at this point. I suggest going back to Python 2.7 instead of trying to debug the script for Python 3.0.

Comment: I tried this on python 2.7 but still got "Build dynamic library for project" exception.